# Truncate span inside td

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using Materialize classes to create a "photo placeholder" to the user which contains the first letter of his name.

I'm having trouble with long names inside the `<td>` tag. I do not want the name to break when it's too long. Because of that, I've tried to apply `class="truncate"` into the spam that contains the name, but it failed to truncate.

How can I solve this?

```css
main {
  padding: 16px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.photo-placeholder {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}

.truncate {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<main>

  <table id="table1" class="white z-depth-1 centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">
          <span class="photo-placeholder">P</span>
          <span class="truncate">Pedro Luis Arend Gonçalves</span>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Col 2">Info 2</td>
        <td data-label="Col 3">Info 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</main>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qt9wp4y/11/)

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: The text seems to be truncated when it's longer than its container `<td>`. Do you want it to work differently? Can you help to clarify your desired functionality and/or the problem?

Comment: I've added now a image of how I want the result to be like. The name needs to be on the side of the "photo placeholder" and truncate inside the td if needed.

Comment: You've declared `display` in `truncate` to be `block`, which means it will move to the next line when paired with `photo-placeholder`, which is declared with `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I just did two things and working fine.
1- add float left to photo-placeholder span
2- add these properties to .truncate span
margin-left: 25%;
padding-top: 4%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "truncate" class sets the element to `display:block`, which puts it on its own line.

One solution might be to set it to `display:inline-block` and set it's width to the remaining space in the table cell. Below, I've calculated the appropriate width by using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). I've also eliminated the white space between the two `<span>` elements so it won't contribute extra width.

```css
main {
  padding: 16px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.photo-placeholder {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}

#table1 .truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<main>

  <table id="table1" class="white z-depth-1 centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">
          <span class="photo-placeholder">P
          </span><span class="truncate">Pedro Luis Arend Gonçalves</span>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Col 2">Info 2</td>
        <td data-label="Col 3">Info 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</main>
```

To avoid having to calculate the width, you can simply `float` the placeholder left, like this:

```css
main {
  padding: 16px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.photo-placeholder {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<main>

  <table id="table1" class="white z-depth-1 centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">
          <span class="photo-placeholder">P</span>
          <span class="truncate">Pedro Luis Arend Gonçalves</span>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Col 2">Info 2</td>
        <td data-label="Col 3">Info 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</main>
```

Here's a different method that uses a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) container. I like this one because it's easier to vertically center the two elements with `align-items:center`.

```css
main {
  padding: 16px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.photoContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.photo-placeholder {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<main>

  <table id="table1" class="white z-depth-1 centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">
          <div class="photoContent">
            <span class="photo-placeholder">P</span>
            <span class="truncate">Pedro Luis Arend Gonçalves</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Col 2">Info 2</td>
        <td data-label="Col 3">Info 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</main>
```

Comment: It works! But the name become's a little weird, doesn't? I've notices that if I break the line between the <span> tags it does the same thing as the display:block thing

Comment: That's probably because of the white space between the two elements. Because of the way the width of the truncated element is calculated, the total width of the two elements plus that white space is greater than 100% of the container's width and the second element wraps to the next line. That's why I removed the white space between the two elements in my first example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `width` or `max-width` style rule set to the element as well. Otherwise, as long as there is room to grow, it will take up that space. Adding the style rule `max-width: 50px;` did the trick for me in your example.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwumn8g1/) Try adding the following CSS:

```
.photo-placeholder {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 40px;
}

table.centered tbody tr td:first-child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```